# django 2 no reverse macth on passing url <a href="{% url 'detailinfo' infos.id %}"></a>

Tags: django, python-3.x

my model = Infos
 this my urls.py

```
path('infos/<int:infos_id>/', views.detailinfo, name='detailinfo'),
```

this my views.py

```
#pages detail infos
def detailinfo(request, infos_id):
    infos = get_object_or_404(Infos, pk=infos_id)
    return render(request,'uplus/detailinfo.html',{'infos': infos})
```

the link to access to page detailinfos on my browser
http://127.0.0.1:8080/infos/1/

the url passing

```
<a href="{% url 'detailinfo' infos.id %}"></a>
```

Comment: Did you specify a `namespace` in the `url`? Can you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: Have you tried: `{% url 'detailinfo' infos_id=infos.id %}` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Edit your title with the error rather than your code.